# Query in SQL Server 2015 is causing an issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

My query is:

```
select distinct 
    e.EmployeeId, EmployeeCode, EmployeeName, 
    Cast(d.LogDate as date) AttDate, 
    PunchTimes = Stuff((Select ', ' + convert(varchar, d.LogDate, 8) 
                        from DeviceLogs dl WITH (NoLock) 
                        where dl.UserId = e.EmployeeId 
                          and cast(dl.LogDate as date) = cast(d.LogDate as date) 
                        for XML path('') ), 1, 2, '') 
from 
    Employees e, DeviceLogs d
where 
    e.EmployeeId = d.UserId 
    --and cast(d.LogDate as date) between cast(@FromDate as date) and cast(@ToDate as date) 
    and cast(d.LogDate as date) between '1-Jun-2019' and '1-Jun-2019'
group by 
    e.EmployeeId, EmployeeCode, EmployeeName, Cast(d.LogDate as date)
```

I get this error:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Column 'DeviceLogs.LogDate' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Use of GROUP BY clause without any aggregate function is the issue.

Comment: The error is clear but the query is definitely not. It seems there's a subquery in the `SELECT` clause and filtering uses localized date literals which guarantees conversion issues

Comment: BTW `NOLOCK` means `read dirty data, locks or not, while taking excessive locks`. Looks like you encountered a performance problem and tried to cover it up with `NOLOCK`. This will actually make things *worse*.

Comment: As for the error, it's caused by the subquery. Since it's only a subquery, not an actuall aggregate function, it *can't* contain any columns that aren't already in the GROUP BY clause or an aggregate function. In SQL Server 2017 you could use `STRING_AGG` for this. In earlier versions you'll have to use the SQLCLR method for string aggregation

Comment: There is no SQL Server **2015** version - we have 2012, 2014, 2016, 2017 and 2019 in the works - take your pick

Answer (score 1):

I recommend avoiding `group by` and using `select distinct` in the subquery instead:

```
select e.*, 
       stuff( (select ', ' + convert(varchar(255), d.LogDate, 8) 
               from DeviceLogs dl
               where dl.UserId = e.EmployeeId and 
                     cast(dl.LogDate as date) = e.AttDate
               for XML path('')
              ), 1, 2, ''
            ) as PunchTimes
from (select distinct e.EmployeeId, e.EmployeeCode, e.EmployeeName, 
             Cast(d.LogDate as date) as AttDate
            ) 
      from Employees e join
           DeviceLogs d
           on e.EmployeeId = d.UserId 
      where d.LogDate >= '2019-06-01' and
            d.LogDate < '2019-06-02'
     ) e;
```

Note:

- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.
- Use standard date formats, either `'YYYYMMDD'` or `'YYYY-MM-DD'`.
- Qualify *all* column references when a table refers to more than one table.
- Always use a length when specifying `VARCHAR()` and similar types.  The default varies by context and may cause hard-to-debug errors.
- Only use `WITH (NOLOCK)` if you really understand what it is doing.  I am guessing that you don't understand it thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `cast(dl.LogDate as date)` column to your Group By clause.

CORRECTION:  misread the aliases round in the subquery; the issue is that the correlated reference to d.LogDate is being used in the subquery.  Given the following DDL

```
CREATE TABLE Employees (EmployeeId INT PRIMARY KEY
, EmployeeCode INT
, EmployeeName VARCHAR(255))

CREATE TABLE DeviceLogs (UserId INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Employees(EmployeeId), LogDate DATETIME)
```

This works:-

```
select distinct e.EmployeeId, EmployeeCode, EmployeeName, Cast(d.LogDate as date) AttDate, 
    PunchTimes = Stuff((Select ', ' + convert(varchar, dl.LogDate, 8) 
                       from DeviceLogs dl WITH (NoLock) 
                        where dl.UserId = e.EmployeeId and cast(dl.LogDate as 
                        date) = cast(d.LogDate as date) for XML path('') ),1, 2, '') 
from Employees e, DeviceLogs d
where e.EmployeeId = d.UserId 

    and cast(d.LogDate as date) between '1-Jun-2019' and '1-Jun-2019'
group by e.EmployeeId, EmployeeCode, EmployeeName, Cast(d.LogDate as date)
```

But the original query does not:-

```
select distinct e.EmployeeId, EmployeeCode, EmployeeName, Cast(d.LogDate as date) AttDate, 
    PunchTimes = Stuff((Select ', ' + convert(varchar, d.LogDate, 8) 
                       from DeviceLogs dl WITH (NoLock) 
                        where dl.UserId = e.EmployeeId and cast(dl.LogDate as 
                        date) = cast(d.LogDate as date) for XML path('') ),1, 2, '') 
from Employees e, DeviceLogs d
where e.EmployeeId = d.UserId 

    and cast(d.LogDate as date) between '1-Jun-2019' and '1-Jun-2019'
group by e.EmployeeId, EmployeeCode, EmployeeName, Cast(d.LogDate as date)
```

Comment: It's already there. I suspect the error complains about the *subquery*, not the outer query

Comment: No it isn't, ```Cast(d.LogDate as date)``` is, but not ```cast(dl.LogDate as date)```.  Easy to miss, but they are both required in the GROUP BY, or the reference to cast(dl.LogDate as date) changing to d.LogDate.

Comment: Adding `cast(dl.LogDate as date)` to the GROUP BY clause is impossible as `dl` appears only in the subquery, which is trying to perform a string aggregation, the same way SQL Server 2017's `STRING_AGG` or MySQL's `GROUP_CONCAT` would. This can't work in previous versions. Gordon Linoff shows how this can work by *removing* GROUP BY entirely. After all, it's only used to provide distinct keys for the string aggregation. If the query contained other aggregates like SUM, it wouldn't be possible to use `DISTINCT`

Comment: Apologies, you're right, I misread the references round in the subquery.  The actual solution (well without rewriting, but that's a different problem) is to use the dl.LogDate within the subquery rather than the d.LogDate.

```PunchTimes = Stuff((Select ', ' + convert(varchar, dl.LogDate, 8) 
                       from DeviceLogs dl WITH (NoLock) 
                        where dl.UserId = e.EmployeeId and cast(dl.LogDate as 
                        date) = cast(d.LogDate as date) for XML path('') ),1, 2, '') ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    select distinct e.EmployeeId, EmployeeCode, EmployeeName, Cast(d.LogDate as date) AttDate, 
        PunchTimes = Stuff((Select ', ' + convert(varchar, d.LogDate, 8) from DeviceLogs dl WITH (NoLock) 
            where dl.UserId = e.EmployeeId and cast(dl.LogDate as date) = cast(d.LogDate as date) for XML path('') ),1, 2, '') 
    from Employees e, DeviceLogs d
    where e.EmployeeId = d.UserId 
        --and cast(d.LogDate as date) between cast(@FromDate as date) and cast(@ToDate as date) 
        and cast(d.LogDate as date) between '1-Jun-2019' and '1-Jun-2019'
    group by e.EmployeeId, EmployeeCode, EmployeeName, AttDate

any aggregate function is not allowed in group by
```

Comment: There are no aggregate functions in `GROUP BY`. `cast` is not an aggregate function